# How to convert a tuple of dictionaries of pyTorch tensors into a dictionary of tensors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, pytorch, tuples

I have a tuple of dictionaries, that hold pyTorch tensors:

```
tuple_of_dicts_of_tensors = (
    {'key_1': torch.tensor([1,1,1]), 'key_2': torch.tensor([4,4,4])},
    {'key_1': torch.tensor([2,2,2]), 'key_2': torch.tensor([5,5,5])},
    {'key_1': torch.tensor([3,3,3]), 'key_2': torch.tensor([6,6,6])}
)
```

Which I would like to transform into a dictionary of tensors:

```
dict_of_tensors = {
    'key_1': torch.tensor([[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3]]),
    'key_2': torch.tensor([[4,4,4], [5,5,5], [6,6,6]])
}
```

How would you recommend doing that? What is the most efficient way?
The tensors are on a GPU device, so a minimal amount of for loops is required.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use torch's built-in [`default_collate()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.default_collate) function:

```py
import torch
from torch.utils.data import default_collate

tuple_of_dicts_of_tensors = (
    {'key_1': torch.tensor([1,1,1]), 'key_2': torch.tensor([4,4,4])},
    {'key_1': torch.tensor([2,2,2]), 'key_2': torch.tensor([5,5,5])},
    {'key_1': torch.tensor([3,3,3]), 'key_2': torch.tensor([6,6,6])}
)

dict_of_tensors = default_collate(tuple_of_dicts_of_tensors)
print(dict_of_tensors)

# >>> {'key_1': tensor([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]),
#      'key_2': tensor([[4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6]])}
```

It is quite a powerful function, although its documentation might not be immediately clear. Shortened quote from the documentation:

> Function that takes in a batch of data and puts the elements within the batch into a tensor with an additional outer dimension - batch size.
>
> Here is the general input type (based on the type of the element within the batch) to output type mapping:
>
> - torch.Tensor -> torch.Tensor (with an added outer dimension batch size)
> - Mapping[K, V_i] -> Mapping[K, default_collate([V_1, V_2, …])]

In your case, the elements of the batch (i.e. your tuple) are mappings (i.e. your dicts) of tensors. So,

- in a first step the mappings get "moved to the outside" – meaning you end up with one dict (second bullet from the quoted doc);
- in a second step, the function is again applied to all the values of your dicts, which are tensors – meaning, for each key, the tensors are collated together into one tensor with a new batch dimension (first bullet from the quoted doc).

In other words, you can think of the task of `default_collate()` as *moving the batch dimension inward*: a batch of *A* objects containing *B* objects (in your case: a tuple of dictionary objects containing tensor objects) becomes an *A* object of batches of *B* objects (in your case: a dictionary of batches of tensors, where each "batch of tensors" is again a single tensor with a new, prepended batch dimension).

Answer (score 0):

In this code, dict_of_lists_of_tensors is first constructed by using a dictionary comprehension to extract the tensors for each key from the tuple of dictionaries. Then, for each key, the list of tensors is stacked along a new dimension using torch.stack(), which gives you the desired dictionary of tensors. This approach minimizes the usage of explicit loops and takes advantage of PyTorch's GPU-accelerated operations.

```html
import torch

tuple_of_dicts_of_tensors = (
    {'key_1': torch.tensor([1,1,1]), 'key_2': torch.tensor([4,4,4])},
    {'key_1': torch.tensor([2,2,2]), 'key_2': torch.tensor([5,5,5])},
    {'key_1': torch.tensor([3,3,3]), 'key_2': torch.tensor([6,6,6])}
)
dict_of_lists_of_tensors = {key: [d[key] for d in tuple_of_dicts_of_tensors] for key in tuple_of_dicts_of_tensors[0]}
dict_of_tensors = {key: torch.stack(tensor_list) for key, tensor_list in dict_of_lists_of_tensors.items()}

print(dict_of_tensors)
```

OUTPUT:-

```html
{'key_1': tensor([[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3]]), 'key_2': tensor([[4, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 5],
        [6, 6, 6]])}
```

Comment: I am sorry, it was a mistake. I tried to change it but it told me that "You last voted on this answer yesterday. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited."